# How to display 3rd level category in Magento?

Tags: php, magento

I'm currently trying to display a third level category in my filter, this is the website http://yaubrothers.xist2test.com/index.php/products.html.

I would like to display the child category of the sub category as a dropdown?

Thank you

```
<?php if($this->canShowBlock()): ?>
<div class="block block-layered-nav<?php if (!$this->getLayer()->getState()->getFilters()): ?> block-layered-nav--no-filters<?php endif; ?>">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Shop By') ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content toggle-content">
        <?php echo $this->getStateHtml() ?>
        <?php if ($this->getLayer()->getState()->getFilters()): ?>
            <div class="actions"><a href="<?php echo $this->getClearUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Clear All') ?></a></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if($this->canShowOptions()): ?>
            <p class="block-subtitle block-subtitle--filter"><?php echo $this->__('Filter') ?></p>
            <dl id="narrow-by-list">
                <?php $_filters = $this->getFilters() ?>
                <?php foreach ($_filters as $_filter): ?>
                <?php if($_filter->getItemsCount()): ?>
                    <dt><?php echo $this->__($_filter->getName()) ?></dt>
                    <dd><?php echo $_filter->getHtml() ?></dd>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </dl>
            <script type="text/javascript">decorateDataList('narrow-by-list')</script>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Can you show your relevant code?

Comment: I have added the code

Comment: I'm not having any errors, if you click on the web link and click on the filter category, then click noodles here is where I would like to display the third level category, rather what is happening if you click noodle it takes you to noodles products and if you was to click category again this is where you will find the 3rd level. Hope this clear.

Answer (score 0):

Use Below code

```
<div class="left_content">
 <div class="menu">
<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
<?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category') ?>
<?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>
        <ul id="menu">
        <?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
                <li class="sub">
                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>"><?php echo $_category->getName() ?></a>
                <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()) ?>
                <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                <?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0): ?>
                    <ul>
                     <?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>
                        <li>
                            <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>">
                            <?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?>
                            <!--sub sub category-->
                            <?php $_subcategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_subcategory->getId()) ?>
                            <?php $_subsubcategories = $_subcategory->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                            <?php if (count($_subsubcategories) > 0): ?>
                             <ul>
                             <?php foreach($_subsubcategories as $_subsubcategory): ?>
                             <li>
                                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subsubcategory) ?>">
                             <?php echo $_subsubcategory->getName() ?>
                                </a>
                             </li>
                      <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                 <?php endif; ?>
                             <!--sub sub category-->
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                <?php endif; ?>
                </li>
         <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
      <?php endif; ?>
   </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this code seems to add the sub category to the menu? Rather what I am trying to do here is to add the child category to the sub category in shop by filter area

Comment: do you current category  sub-category list on filter?

Comment: Yes, the current category and sub category is listed on the filter, I would like to also list the child category.

Comment: Please see this link http://magentoo.blogspot.in/2014/01/get-all-subcategories-of-parent-category-magento.html

Comment: if you want to show it on layered navigation on category page than create phtml file and put it in template/catalog/category
and call it in layout/catalog.xml

Comment: At the moment I don't have "template/catalog/category" and I don't understand what you mean by call it in layout/catalog.xml

Comment: create category folder and put phtml file under that folder

Comment: What will the phtml need to be called?

Comment: phtml file is required for category fetching for 3rd level

Comment: whatever you like for example : sub_category.phtml

Comment: Ok, I have created the file and inserted this code, what will I need to do next?

Comment: open catalog.xml file and put below code under <catalog_category_default translate="label"> and <catalog_category_layered translate="label">
<reference name="left">
            <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products.sub" template="catalog/category/sub_category.phtml" />
</reference>

Comment: Having no luck with this, please have a look at my link http://yaubrothers.xist2test.com/index.php/products.html, the child categories are dumping out but I need to display into the filter, any help?